# How to take a screenshot on android 4.0+

Tags: android, screenshot, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I heard that Android 4.0+ support user to capture screenshot without root. So, I think that It must provide some APIs that help developers build this feature to their app, Right? If it have, Could you please tell me what they are?

Comment: Where does it say that users can take a screenshot?

Comment: Users can now share what's on their screens more easily by taking screenshots. Hardware buttons let them snap a screenshot and store it locally. Afterward, they can view, edit, and share the screen shot in Gallery or a similar app. (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html)

Comment: Directed at older versions but this might be a solution. It's also unclear if rooting is required but I'd assume from the reported success it's not required.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/screenshot-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for an app to take a screenshot. The screenshot is placed into a standard folder, but some devices use different folders, and there is no API to get the correct folder name.
Users can take screenshots by pressing volume-down and power on most phones. On Some devices it is done by power+home, on some by hand swipe. There is no API to tell how to take a screenshot on the current device.